# How to block IP address on Apache when it comes from proxy

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, ip, restrictions

I have the URL I need to restrict access for specific IP (10.0.0.5).
When I do it for direct access in the next way it works perfect:

```
<Location /incoming>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from 10.0.0.5
    Allow from all
</Location>
```

But , when this IP comes from Proxy (Proxy IP: 192.168.1.43) this solution does not work.
This what I see in log:

> 10.0.0.5, 192.168.1.43 - - [24/May/2017:16:03:54 +0300] "POST /incoming HTTP/1.0" 200 698 0/6899 "-" "-"

I tried to do the next - add Proxy section:

```
<Proxy /incoming >
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from 10.0.0.5
    Allow from all
</Proxy>
```

It does not help too.

I need your help, friends!!!

Answer (score 5):

If the proxy sets the X-Forwarded-For header, you should be able to use this:

```
<Location /incoming>
    Order Deny,Allow
    SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-For "10.0.0.5" DenyAccess
    Deny from env=DenyAccess
</Location>
```

`Order Deny,Allow` is an allow-by-default directive, which gives access unless a deny-rule matches. SetEnvIf conditionally sets an environment flag based on the value of the X-Forwarded-For. The one deny rule here triggers only if that flag is set. If no deny rule is triggered, access is allowed.

You can also reference `env` flags in `Require` blocks, as illustrated [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_authz_core.html#logic).